# Windows equivalent to "ssh user@server 'pidof my_program' "

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, windows-server-2008-r2, raspbian

in order to monitor the activity of a specific process on lots of Raspberry Pi devices connected via LAN to a Linux server, I wrote a simple script that looped into this command:

```
ssh pi@raspberry 'pidof my_program'
```

as many times as the devices number and returned me the return value of the command for each of them.

Now, one of our customers only has a Windows IIS web server with PuTTY and WinSCP installed.

I am totally noob with Windows, and I don't know if there's an elegant way to have the same output as the command above.

Could anyone help me?

Note: My Client OS is Raspbian; 
Note: My Server OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Thank you,
Riccardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PuTTY you may also have plink.exe which is on the PuTTY download page -> http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

plink.exe pi@raspberry "/sbin/pidof my_program"

Comment: `move plink.exe C:\windows\ssh.exe" and most of your typical linux SSH commands will work without modification ;)